# Custom Post Type - Main page for certain posts

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, permalinks, themes

I've successfully added a custom post type.

```
register_post_type('case',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Cases'),
                'singular_name' => __('Case')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields', 'page-attributes')
        )

    );
```

And I've created a page called "case" and I have my permalinks configured like this:

```
/%postname%
```

The problem I'm having now is that when I try to access url.com/case I don't get my page "case" but instead I'm looking at the custom post type "case". I think?

Every "case" has its own url --> url.com/case/xxx. I don't want to change this but instead be able to change the layout for the custom page "main" page that represents all the cases instead of a "page" called case.

Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1):

I got it by searching some more on google.

```
'has_archive' => true,
```

This line is vital.

Found out I had to rename my custom template pages to **archive-"the custom type name"** which in this case was.

```
archive-case.php
```

Because of this I could remove my "static" page called case and let the system pick the right template page for the custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

In the arguments (`$args`) parameter of the [**`register_post_type`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function, there is a variable named `rewrite`. By default it is *true*, try to set it to *false*.